# Cardinality of the function measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

How can I determinate the cardinality of the set of the all funtions $f: E \to \mathbb{R}^{*}$ be are Lebesgue measurables?
Here $\mathbb{R}^{*}$ denote the set of extended reals.

I know that the Lebesgue measurable set is uncountable, but how can I calculate that cardinality?

Comment: The question is to find the $\#(\{f: E\to \mathbb{R}^{*}: f, E, \quad \text{measurables set}\})$, where $\#A$ denote the cardinality of the set $A$. I don't understand your hint.

Comment: A lower bound is $2^c,$ since the characteristic function of any subset of the Cantor middle thirds set is Lebesgue measurable. Now show that $2^c$ is also an upper bound, and hence the cardinality equals $2^c.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you. I'm going to try to prove that statement.